# How to prevent counter increment when holding the button

Tags: arduino-ide

I am a newbie and also a noobie. Kindly assist this poor boy over here. 
I am looking for a way to increment a variable by one each time a button is pressed. Current approach is the following :

```
void buttonLoop() {
  int win = 0;
  while (win ==0) {
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  //getButtons() function can be used to test if any button is pressed, or used like:
  //getButtons(TSButtonUpperLeft) to test a particular button, or even like:
  //getButtons(TSButtonUpperLeft|TSButtonUpperRight) to test multiple buttons
  //results are flipped as you would expect when setFlip(true)
  if (display.getButtons(TSButtonUpperLeft)) {
    display.println("Pressed!");
    score++;
    updateScore();
  } else {
    display.println("          ");
  }
  display.setCursor(0, 54);
  if (display.getButtons(TSButtonLowerLeft)) {
    display.println("Pressed!");
    score++;
    updateScore();
  } else {
    display.println("          ");
  }
  display.setCursor(95 - display.getPrintWidth("Pressed!"), 0);
  if (display.getButtons(TSButtonUpperRight)) {
    display.println("Pressed!");
    score++;
    updateScore();
  } else {
    display.println("          ");
  }
  display.setCursor(95 - display.getPrintWidth("Pressed!"), 54);
  if (display.getButtons(TSButtonLowerRight)) {
    display.println("Pressed!");
    score++;
    updateScore();
  } else {
    display.println("          ");
  }
}
}
```

In my case, the counter will keep increasing if I do not let go of the button. How do I make it so that the counter will only increase by 1 even if i continue holding onto the button.

Thank you for all the kind souls in this society :)

Comment: Look for the Bounce2 library in the IDE library manager.

Comment: check to see if the button was released before allowing the counter to increment again

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in this thread:

[How to connect Big Dome Button with arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/70415/how-to-connect-big-dome-button-with-arduino)

That thread explains how to wire up a switch and write code that increments a counter each time a button is pressed.

The bits you care about:

Connect one lead of the switch to a digital input, and the other lead to ground.

Then set your switch pin to `INPUT_PULLUP` mode. Now your switch will read HIGH until it's pressed, then it will read LOW.

create a variable at the top of your code called buttonState:

```
byte buttonState = HIGH;
```

Also define an unsigned long variable nextReadMillis:

```
unsigned long nextReadMillis = 0;
```

and a pressCount variable:

```
unsigned int pressCount = 0;
```

And define a debounceTime:

```
#define debounceTime 50
```

In your loop, do something like this:

```
void loop() {
    //Get the new millis(value)
    unsigned long newMillis = millis();

    //only look at the new button value if enough time has elapsed.
    if (newMillis >= nextReadMillis) {
       byte newButtonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

       //Only do something if the button state has changed
       if (buttonState != newButtonState) {
          buttonState = newButtonState;
          nextReadMillis = newMillis + debounceTime;
          //If the button is now in the pressed (LOW) state, increment the count
          if (buttonState == LOW) {
              pressCount++;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

That's pseudo-code. It likely has syntax errors. It's not meant to be copy/pasted. Use it as a guide for your project.

The code using `millis()` is a version of "software debouncing." Electrical switches tend to "jitter" or "bounce" between their on and off states very rapidly when they are first pressed/released. By only checking for state changes after a brief delay, you ignore the jitter in the readings.

You can adjust the value of debounceTime up or down a little. A value of 50 is 1/20th of a second, which should make your button presses quite responsive, but still debounce the switch well. If you find your count sometimes increases by more than one for a button press, you can increase the value to 100 or even 500, although at 500 (1/2 second) the button won't respond to really rapid presses